# ionic build ios throws a promise Rejection error

Tags: ios, build.gradle

I am setting up a build environment in a new mac for my project.
I am able to successfully run the 'gulp' command followed by the 'ionic build android'.
The .apk file generated is working as expected.
but my 'ionic build ios' is throwing the following error.

The following build commands failed:

> CompileXIB MyProjectDirectory/Resources/ExternalFormViewController.xib
>   (1 failure)

CordovaError:

> Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command:
>   xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/MyProjectDirectory/Bala/InterimDirectory/ProjectFolder/ProjectSubFolder/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,MyProjectDirectory.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyProjectDirectory,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/MyProjectDirectory/Bala/InterimDirectory/ProjectFolder/ProjectSubFolder/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/MyProjectDirectory/Bala/InterimDirectory/ProjectFolder/ProjectSubFolder/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch'
>       at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some issue with XCode or some dependencies not being at the expected place.

Could you try the following (add sudo if it fails for permission reasons):

> npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true